# How to get names of first 200 Facebook users using Python?

Tags: python, facebook

I am trying to get the names of first 200 Facebook users.
I am using Python and BeautifulSoup

The approach which I'm using is that instead of using Graph API, I'm trying to get the names using the title of the webpage.(The title of the profile webpage is the name of the person)

The first user is Zuckerberg(id:4). I want names till 200.

Here's what I've tried.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

x=4

while(x<=200):
    print BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://www.facebook.com/"+str(x))).title.string
    x+=1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What results are you seeing?

Comment: @kindall it is not working properly as expected.  '

Comment: Would you take your car to a mechanic and say "it is not working properly as expected?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I concur with the other commenters that there is barely enough information to figure out what the problem is. But reading between the lines a bit, I imagine the OP is expecting that results for pages such as

https://www.facebook.com/4
which gets redirected to https://www.facebook.com/zuck, Mark Zuckerberg's page, and https://www.facebook.com/5
which gets redirected to https://www.facebook.com/ChrisHughes, another early Facebook employee, will continue to work for further arbitrary user IDs the OP plugs in. In fact, I believe this trick did used to work in the past... until someone posted a spreadsheet of the first 2000 Facebook users somewhere, and Facebook clamped down on this hole (this is from memory, I bet there's a news story out there if someone feels like digging).

Anyway, trying further user IDs in the URL such as:
https://www.facebook.com/7 now gives a "Sorry, this page isn't available" response. To the OP, I don't think there's any easy way you can code around this -- Zuck obviously doesn't care that you're harvesting his own page, but I guess he's not keen on letting you scrape the entire Facebook user list. Sorry.

**Update**: you might still be able to get away with such harvesting using Facebook's Graph API -- it appears that GETs of pages like https://graph.facebook.com/100 will work for most User IDs. You should be able to script up what you need from there (if I were Facebook, I would have rate-limiting in place to prevent mass harvesting, but you'll have to try and see what you get for yourself.) Here's a [script](http://pythonnotesbyajay.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-send-messages-to-billions-of.html) similar to what you're trying to do.